# Data Not Being Parsed Correctly

Tags: php, string, parsing

I have a simple data format that goes as follows:

```
stuff/stuff/stuff
```

An example would be:

```
data/test/hello/hello2
```

In order to retrieve a certain piece of data, one would use my parser, which tries to do the following:

In `data/test/hello/hello2`

You want to retrieve the data under `data/test` (which is `hello`). My parser's code is below:

```
function getData($data, $pattern)
{
    $info = false;

    $dataLineArray = explode("\n", $data);

    foreach($dataLineArray as &$line)
    {
        if (strpos($line,$pattern) !== false) {

            $lineArray = explode("/", $line);
            $patternArray = explode("/", $pattern);

            $iteration = 0;


            foreach($lineArray as &$lineData)
            {
                if($patternArray[$iteration] == $lineData)
                {
                    $iteration++;
                }
                else
                {
                    $info = $lineData;
                }
            }


        }
    }

    return $info;
}
```

However, it always seems to return the last item, which in this case is `hello2`:

`echo getData("data/test/hello/hello2", "data/test");`

Gives Me;

`hello2`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You only want the 'hello' part? And why are you exploding `$data` on newlines if there are no newlines?

Comment: Yes. Nothing after that.

Comment: You set `$info` each time through the loop. When the loop is done, it will contain the assignment from the last time it was set.

Comment: People use regex when they don't need and ignore when they need. Basically, `data/test/(\w+)` is pattern you are looking for: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the first element after the pattern, put `break` in the loop:

```
        foreach($lineArray as $lineData)
        {
            if($patternArray[$iteration] == $lineData)
            {
                $iteration++;
            }
            elseif ($iteration == count($patternArray))
            {
                $info = $lineData;
                break;
            }
        }
```

I also check `$iteration == count($patternArray)` so that it won't return intermediate elements, e.g.

```
/data/foo/test/hello/hello2
```

will return `hello` rather than `foo`.

P.S. There doesn't seem to be any reason to use references instead of ordinary variables in your loops, since you never assign to the reference variables.

Comment: OP wants only the first element after the pattern.

Comment: I've revised my answer, I think it matches the OP's needs better.